# GCP CDN service account is not created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cdn, service-accounts, google-cdn

Currently I try to use Google's CDN to reduce the traffic to my Google cloud storage.

I followed the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-bucket) to configure the CDN and the bucket, first for public access, then for private access with signed urls [doc](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls)

/edit steps I made:

- Created a bucket, copied a file into it and made it public accessible.
- Reserved an external ip adress.
- Created a load balancer with, created a backed bucket which can access the bucket.

After that the files are available via CDN.

After that I made the following changes:

- Added a singing key to the backend bucket.

When I use the bucket url to generate a signed url with the gcloud tool I am able to access the files:

```
gcloud compute sign-url \
"https://storage.cloud.google.com/*/sampleFile" \
--key-name test-sign \
--key-file test-sign \
--expires-in 30m \
--validate
```

Now should be a service account automatically added, but when I run:

```
gsutil iam ch \
  serviceAccount:service-MYPROJECTNUMBER@cloud-cdn-fill.iam.gserviceaccount.com:objectViewer \
  gs://MYBUCKET
```

there is an error:

```
 400 Service account service-MYPROJECTNUMBER@cloud-cdn-fill.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not exist.
```

I tried to create an account manually and add it to the bucket, but when I try to access the urls via CDN there is an error:

> ```
> 403. That’s an error.
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL /example-signed/SampleFile.jpg from this server. That’s all we know.
> ```

I think that the CDN does not have access to my bucket. According to the instructions, this should happen via the service account, which should be created "automatically" in the following step.

[Doc](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#configuring_permissions)

I have now tried several times, but nowhere is a service account created for me.  I have now manually created a service account, but I do not know how to assign it to the CDN.

Someone has a hint for me?

Comment: The service account is created automatically. Adding the service account to the bucket is the next step in your document link. Edit your question and show how the bucket is configured for the CDN.

Comment: The problem is that the account is not created. I tried it multiple times in different projects now. The account should be created when i add an singing key to the bucket, but there is always the error that the service account is not there.
I edited my question to show what i have done

Comment: Go to your billing account and make sure that there are no issues.

Comment: Thx for the idea, i checked it but everything is green and the payments are valid

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're using the correct project number in place of MYPROJECTNUMBER? You need to use the project number that owns the backend bucket. You can find the project number at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/settings. Creating your own service account won't do anything useful because Cloud CDN won't be allowed to impersonate it.

Comment: @elving you sir are the REAL MVP! I was using the project-id the whole time instead of the project number. With your comment i realized that, thanks a lot! Now its working